# Android headphone detection

Tags: java, android

I have an app that will speak text messages to the user. I want to make it so that when the user hits a button called "Headphones on" the app will only speak to it when headphones are detected. Is there a command that will allow me to detect if headphones are plugged in or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a broadcast made when the headphones are plugged in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

You need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive this and perform your required actions.

Answer (score 4):

It seems in this case you just want to check if headphone are connected before to start the audio playout, so you should use audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
    // Play audio...
}
```